# How can I create a 'getLengthAtPoint()' function for a curved path created via svg/raphaeljs?

Tags: svg, raphael

I need a way to calculate the length between two points on a curved path created via Raphaeljs.  For example, if I have the following path: `M10,10T30,50T60,100T80,200T300,400`, and I need to know the coordinates of a point that is 150 pixels from that start of the path.  The  pythagorean theorem cannot be used because the path is curved.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is a possible solution to how to find the distance from the beginning of the path to any one of the points which were used to define it.  The idea is to to create a temporary sub path of the original path for each of the points which make it up, and then use 'getToalLength()' to calculate the distance of this sub-path.  This distance reflects the distance in the entire original path starting from the first point up to the current point.  Now, after the distance has been calculated, it can be stored, and the temporary path can be removed.  This way we can calculate and store the distance from the beginning of the original path to each of the points which make it up.  Here is the code I use (a bit simplified to focus just on this goal):

```
            var pointsAry = [["M",10,10],["T",30,50],["T",60,100],["T",80,200],["T",300,400]], subPath, path = [];
            for (var i = 0 ; i < pointsArray.length ; i++) {
                path.push(pointsAry[i]);
                subPath = paper.path(path).attr({ "stroke-opacity": 0 }); // make the path invisible
                pointsAry[i].subPathSum = subPath.getTotalLength();
                subPath.remove();
            }
```

`paper` is created via [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) which also supplies the `getTotalLength()` function.  Note the lines are created invisibly because their opacity is 0, and anyhow they are immediately removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the SVG DOM [getPointAtLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) method

`SVGPoint getPointAtLength(in float distance)`

e.g. `var point = document.getElementById("pathId").getPointAtLength(150);`

Comment: Hi Robert, I made a mistake in the example above for which your answer is perfect... I'm sorry !  I meant to ask for the above path - M10,10,T30,50T60,100T80,200T300,400 - How can find the length from the beginning of the path to a specific x,y pair of coordinates which is on the path (e.g. 80,200) ?  this is the opposite or complement of 'getPointAtLength'... Thanks and sorry for the confusion.